The function that has not been called still reports an error in the link stage,
but the same code in the teaching demonstration runs without reporting an error.
main.cpp
#include <iostream>

void Log(const char* message);

static int Multiply(int a, int b) {
    Log("Multiply");
    return a * b;
}

int main() {
    // std::cout << Multiply(5,8) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::cin.get();
}


log.cpp
#include <iostream>

void Loge(const char* message) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}


As you can see, The multiply function calls the function log. But the function  multiply has "static" which means it doesn't been used in any other cpp files. And the only call of this function is been //(annotated).
So the function multiply is never used.(Clion also reports this)
So, my teacher click build and no error in his vs2017.
He said this log function is never used. So the link stage doesn't check this name.
But I get a error in my CLion 2024.(Of course I know "Loge" is not same as "Log")
Why?
search on the internet
The reason

function multiply can only  used is main.cpp, but in main.cpp, there is no calling of it. so multply is never used. so function log is never used. Why link stage still check its name?

What is the exact error message?

@Epidermis The declaration doesn't matter. The odr-use decides that there must be definition for the function.

@user17732522 that makes sense

Ignoring unused function depends on the compiler and how the project is structured, MSVC (visual studio) accepts it, which is likely what your instructor uses.
While gcc (and mingw which clion uses) refuses it at link time and can be convinced to accept it by adding the flag
-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files

to force the linker to ignore missing symbols (which is not recommended) or
-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections

to get the compiler to put every function in a section and remove unused sections, this can increase or decrease binary size and may drop unused static objects in other translation units resulting in weird non-conformant behavior in some cases (so also not recommended)

When mentioning -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections I think it is a good idea to also always warn that it will drop things that shouldn't be dropped, making the behavior non-standard-conforming.

Maybe you are right. Actually, he said "you don't use multiply function in main.cpp but the it may think you could call this function in other cpp file, so it should check the inside log function. " In this condition, if we "tell it" that we don't use the multiply function (add static) , then there is no link error.

@FranzKafka as pointed in the other answer the program is not 100% correct, how much "convincing" is needed to get the compiler to allow it depends on the compiler, static is enough for visual studio while gcc needs more steps

It doesn't matter whether or not the function Multiply is actually called.
If a function (Log) is named in an expression, then (with some exceptions that are not relevant here), that is considered a so-called odr-use of the function.
If a function is odr-used anywhere in the program, then there must be a definition of the function available somewhere in the program. Otherwise the program is IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required).
For none of this the function linkage (static), or whether the function containing the odr-use is itself odr-used, matters.
There are no requirements imposed on a compiler for a program that is IFNDR. The compiler doesn't need to succeed compiling it and if it does succeed compiling it, then there is no requirement for it to behave in any specific way (equivalent to undefined behavior).
So both compilers are behaving correctly. The program is invalid, but the compiler is not required to diagnose it.


He said this log function is never used. So the link stage doesn't check this name.

That is generally wrong and depends on the specific compiler/linker. The program is invalid from the point-of-view of the C++ standard as described above.
Of course compilers and linkers may be configurable so that they behave that way. See for example the other answer already posted here.

Well, I don't know. Those teaching videos were 7 years ago. Maybe c++ changed? I found his original words.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4s55GgAg0I&list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb&index=7

It is in 6:59. I don't know which is right. Maybe I misunderstand or miss something important? Could you please take a look?

@FranzKafka don't take everyone's words as the absolute truth, everyone is subject to mistakes, just learn what you find useful and build cool stuff with it, and as a personal opinion those videos can help you start using c++ but they don't teach the best ways to use c++ or even the best practices, they are useful but they are not a reference material.
